# Extra Tags are required

Tags: feature-request

More Tags are required for few postures in "Yoga". There are many more postures. But currently required tags are mentioned as below,

```
1) Wheel-pose
2) Head-Stand
3) Dead-Body-pose
```

There is at least single question available on each above required tag.

Or, should single 'Yoga' tag contain all the postures?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are a bit confused on [the point of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) on Stack Exchange.

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

....

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags.

I know that the philosophy of when to create tags varies a bit across the sites. In SF&F, we have a general rule that you don't add a tag for one-offs where only one question exists in the category, particularly if it's covered by other tags and our rule of thumb is "Can you imagine an expert on the topic of the tag clicking into it to find questions they might be able to answer?" `yoga` makes sense because we have many questions on the topic, and there are experts in it. `wheel-pose` makes a bit less sense because it is not a common question, and it's doubtful that there's someone who has specialized in it.

It's a reasonable question to ask why we might restrict creation of new tags. First of all, it helps reduce clutter, tags that are only used once, or even never used after reclassification. Secondly, it helps prevent tag decay where the tag is used once for one case (where it might be valid) and months to years later, someone else sees the tag name, thinks "Oh, that name fits my question", and provides an incorrect tag.

### TL; DR

I don't think these new tags would be useful to the site, but I'm willing to hear your arguments otherwise. :)

Comment: There r thousands of posture in yoga. It is other case here on this site i.e. yoga postures' relevant questions are less as compared to weight training, cardio ....etc. If present then they r in combination with cardio and weight training and all. Particular yoga posture relevant questions r less. Single yoga tag is not sufficient (if we are considering physical aspect of yoga). I am not asking here all the postures relevant tags. I've also read the rules. Few days before, I want to search dead pose in yoga. But I required long time in yoga tag. If tag wil present then it will b in less time.

Comment: @dhanu Was text search failing?

Comment: Yes it failed on main search, I am searching in intellicence (while typing) mode. it worked only when we are in a mode of asking a question in title input box of 'question asking' mode.

Comment: That's odd. Searching for *[yoga] dead body* works fine for me.

Comment: I am asking about intellicence wordings

Comment: @Dhanu: I'm having a failure of comprehension here, I think. What do you mean by "intellicence wordings"?

Comment: Anyways, I am not explaining that now. If thinking from other point of view--if everything would be searchable then there is no need of tag.

Comment: @Dhanu - Everything IS searchable. "Dead body is:question" brings up a page and a half of results, of which the yoga is the first one. Not knowing how to use the search engine fully is not the fault of the tag system (Which would not be well equipped to handle "thousands of poses" in any case).

Comment: But single yoga tag is not sufficient. BTW, I know how to use search engine. Anyways there is no use of discussion because. yoga will remain yoga only. No mind inclusion and no any tag. yoga = 'meaning taken according to convenience'.

Comment: @JohnP, Why r u not giving the name as 'western yoga'. I am thinking that why am I with people who don't know at least word meaning of 'yoga'. Anyways, I am going to leave your site. You please live with your own way of thinking about your 'physical type of yoga'.

Comment: @Dhanu - That is certainly your choice. If you look at the other meta question, I have proposed that the spiritual/mental aspects could be on topic. However, revamping the way the system works to fit the demands of a single user just isn't done on any SE site. I can see different *types* of yoga having individual tags, but not a tag for every yoga post.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - When programming, there are development environments that autoprompt for common words, so that typing a couple of letters and the tab key autocompletes the word. This is "intellisense". It's a convenience thing. I'm assuming that is what they mean.

Comment: @Dhanu - As above, I can see tags such as [yoga] for general quesitons, [hatha-yoga], [ashtanga-yoga], [kundalini-yoga], etc. Just not a new tag for every pose.

Comment: @JohnP, I am not asking you people to behave according to my way. There is no need of giving suggestion that on which site should I go. I was not exactly going to add spiritual things in my questions. I was asking about meditation (pranayam) (after changing some content). Pranayam is the soul of yoga which includes mind involvement and relaxation through breathing. Anyways, you stick to your physical yoga.

Comment: No further comments please. I am going to delete my account.